# Google Sheets - Autofill cells using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, rules

I want cell I2 to autofill the text "completed" only if cell M2 contains the text "t4" or "tfour"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Ar8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set values, use a formula `=IF(OR(A11="t4", A11="tfour"), "completed", "incomplete")`

Comment: I was hoping to set values through a formula using conditional formatting, is this possible?

Comment: No. Conditional format is just for formats, not values.